# How to parse doctype to string as html doctype

Tags: c#, dom, comobject, ihtmldocument

I'm working on C# app to get html file from current IE tab by [EnumWindows](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumWindows).
Now I got HTMLDocument and can parse it to html file from outerHTML  (*{HTMLDocument}.documentElement.outerHTML*) by [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/), but my output html file has not doctype.

I see that **HTMLDocument** has **doctype** property, how can I parse it to string as same as  tag in html file

Comment: Why do you down vote without leave any comment?

Comment: Maybe because there is no code in your message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by casting `htmlDocument.doctype` as dynamic object. Another, you can get other tags which are out of `<html>` tag by looping on `(dynamic)htmlDocument.childNodes` list

```cs
private static void InsertDocType(HTMLDocument htmlDocument, HtmlDocument document)
{
    // get html node
    HtmlNode htmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html");

    // get doctype node from HTMLDocument
    var doctype = (dynamic)htmlDocument.doctype;

    StringBuilder doctypeText = new StringBuilder();
    doctypeText.Append("<!DOCTYPE");
    doctypeText.Append(" ");
    doctypeText.Append(doctype.name);

    // add PUBLIC
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(doctype.publicId))
    {
        doctypeText.Append(" PUBLIC \"");
        doctypeText.Append(doctype.publicId);
        doctypeText.Append("\"");
    }

    // add sytem id
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(doctype.systemId))
    {
        doctypeText.Append(" \"");
        doctypeText.Append(doctype.systemId);
        doctypeText.Append("\"");
    }

    // add close tag
    doctypeText.Append(">");
    doctypeText.Append(Environment.NewLine);

    HtmlCommentNode doctypeNode = document.CreateComment(doctypeText.ToString());
    document.DocumentNode.InsertBefore(doctypeNode, htmlNode);
}
```